# What's the best way to cache static pages in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-4

In order to boost the performance of my Rails 4.0.2 app, I would like to cache the output of some of my static pages:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
  end

  def about_us
  end

  def contact
  end

end
```

In the [Rails Guide on Caching](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) it says that "Page Caching has been removed from Rails 4" and moved into a gem. In the [gem description](https://github.com/rails/actionpack-page_caching) it says, however, that it will be maintained only until Rails 4.1. Some [other observers](http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/page-caching-action-caching-gem-extraction-rails-4-countdown-to-2013) also advise against using Page Caching and endorse [Russian doll caching](http://signalvnoise.com/posts/3113-how-key-based-cache-expiration-works) instead.

So what's the best way to cache a bunch of static pages that will never actually hit the database and only ever change (slightly) if a user signs in?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Tintin81, I'm facing the same problem at the moment. What was your solution? I guess some kind of HTTP caching, but how and when do you expire the page?

Answer (score 5):

You can still using fragment caching for your static pages, although the benefits are obviously more visible with dynamic / DB-driven pages. It's worth considering doing this should you have a lot of partial being rendered or costly view logic. Just wrap your page's template with:

```
# about_us.html.erb
<% cache 'about_us' do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

the first time you hit the page in an environment where `config.action_controller.perform_caching = true`, it'll generate the fragment (which in this case is your whole page), and it'll serve that the next time you reload it. The cache digest will be invalidated when the template is changed:

> The template digest that's added to the cache key is computed by
>   taking an md5 of the contents of the entire template file. This
>   ensures that your caches will automatically expire when you change the
>   template file.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CacheHelper.html